# File upload using Angular and Node

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, file-upload

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- Client uploads a CV as part of a form
- AngularJS sends all the form data (including CV) to the Node server
- Node stores the CV on the server

I just can't seem to get this working. I tried using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to no avail.

So far I'd have the following:

**HTML**

```
<form name="register" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" ng-submit="registerSubmit(user)">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" />
  <input type="file" id="cv" name="cv" ng-model="user.cv" />
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**Angular**

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http){

  $scope.registerSubmit = function(user){
    $http.post("/api/register", user).success(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  });

});
```

**Node** (configured with Express and other modules)

```
app.use("/api", router);
router.post("/api/register", function(req, res){
  //file not coming through and not sure what to do with it here anyway!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make your request encoded as "multipart/form-data". Check this simmilar question: [file upload with $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490021/file-upload-with-http/)