# file upload with $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

**Is this question too difficult?**

I've my client side code with post data variables, and wondering how can I add file data to `$http.post`.

I've seen some examples and either they are using a custom directive or manual form submission, neither of which I'm looking for.

**Client Side:**

```
<input type="file" id="photo">
//file can be accessed using
var photo = document.getElementById("photo").files[0];
$scope.data.photo = photo
```

OR

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("photo", photo);
formData.append("title", $scope.data.title);
this.delegate.insert(formData);
```

Dispatched to service

```
$http.post("/admin/speakers/?" + data, token.body) //token.body = $scope.data
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```

**Expecting Output Server Side** (produced using POSTMAN - a REST client)

```
console.log(request.files, request.body);

{ photo: 
   { fieldname: 'photo',
     originalname: '01.jpg',
     name: 'fbb54fa6d588ac253ca7dab08a904356.jpg',
     encoding: '7bit',
     mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
     path: '/var/folders/jg/hkmz0fdn64g8w1jgf60j2lcw0000gn/T/fbb54fa6d588ac253ca7dab08a904356.jpg',
     extension: 'jpg',
     size: 12279,
     truncated: false,
     buffer: null } } 

{ name: 'SA',
  title: 'Dev',
  company: 'CA',
  bio: 'some bio',
  twitter: '@twitter',
  sessionId: '1' }
```

Comment: If you are able to extend your app with Angular modules, check these: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload and http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-file-upload, both are available as NPM packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `Content-Type header` to `undefined` and the `transformRequest` to `angular.identity` (to not serialize the FormData object):

```
$http.post("/admin/speakers/?" + data, token.body, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    }
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

> Angular’s default transformRequest function will try to serialize our FormData object, so we override it with the identity function to leave the data intact. Angular’s default Content-Type header for POST and PUT requests is application/json, so we want to change this, too. By setting ‘Content-Type’: undefined, the browser sets the Content-Type to multipart/form-data for us and fills in the correct boundary. Manually setting ‘Content-Type’: multipart/form-data will fail to fill in the boundary parameter of the request.
>
> (https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs)